# How to position a div relative to img without a parent div wrapping the img

Tags: jquery, css, image, position, css-position

I am currently writing a little jqueryplugin for preloading images with a statusbar for each image.

The statusbar should be centered horizontally and vertically above each image.

As it should be a plugin I don't want the user need to wrap each image by a relative positioned div in order to position another div relative to the img. Using a cms the user might not even be able to change the way an image is being output.

So what I don't want is this:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <img src="" />
  <div style="position: absolute, ...">100% loaded</div>
</div>
```

What I want is:

```
  <img src="" />
  <div style="position: absolute, ...">100% loaded</div>
```

I tried to place a div right behind the image with jQuery, setting it to position relative and place a div right inside that div positioned absolute. That might work for some cases, but it depends on the css of the img... is it floated or not etc.

Does any CSS- or jQuery-Guru got some suggestions for me? :-)

Cheers

Comment: Why not wrap it and when its loaded, unwrap it?

Comment: The thing is that I need some positioning-technique which works without the wrapping div, because I want the users to feel free if they wrap their images with a div or not. Or did I get you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will wrap `img`s and remove the wrapper when the images are loaded.

```
$('img').each(function () {

  var $img = $(this),
      $percentLoaded = $('<span class="percent-loaded">');

  $img.wrap('<span class="preloader">');

  $img.parent().append($percentLoaded);

  $img.on('load', function () {
    $percentLoaded.fadeOut(5000);
    $img.unwrap();
  });

});
```

Then the CSS would look something like this:

```
.preloader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.preloader .percent-loaded {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/jesuneqo/1/edit

Comment: Hi Bill, first of all thanks! That does the job for me I guess. I had something like this in mind, but thought there could be a "nicer" solution with css only which is also responsive. That fact that it get's messed up when resizing the window is not so important to me I think, because it only appears when the user resizes the window while the images are being loaded. After being loaded the divs will fade out anyways. And if you really need it I could write some on resize-function. What do you think?

Comment: The demo is not working because to get the position, height and width of an image, the image has to be loaded first.

Comment: @haeki I went to work. What Aamit said is true. We just weren't noticing because we are on faster connections. The commentators wanted you to wrap the images dynamically like this which is what I was thinking originally: http://jsbin.com/jesuneqo/1/edit I also updated my answer.